# CORS Play Framework

Tags: java, angular, playframework

I'm developing an Angular 2 application on top of a Play Framework 2.5 (Java) back-end. If I access my endpoints through browser URL, they work fine. However, calling it from the Angular 2 application shows the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:9000/app/myendpoint. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

I have tryed to follow the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/CorsFilter) and create the filter:

In application.conf:

```
play.filters {
  cors {
    pathPrefixes = ["/app"]
    allowedOrigins = null
    allowedHttpMethods = null
  }
```

Filter:

```
import play.mvc.*;
import play.api.http.DefaultHttpFilters; <- error with this import
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter;

public class Filters extends DefaultHttpFilters {
    @Inject public Filters(CORSFilter corsFilter) {
        super(corsFilter);
    }
}
```

In build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ...,
  filters
)
```

Does anyone knows the true solution? Thank you :)

**Working code:**

Filters.java (on project's root)

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Singleton;    
import play.http.HttpFilters;
import play.mvc.EssentialAction;
import play.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter;

@Singleton
public class Filters extends EssentialFilter implements HttpFilters {

    @Inject
    private CORSFilter corsFilter;

    @Override
    public EssentialAction apply(EssentialAction next) {
        return corsFilter.asJava().apply(next);
    }

    @Override
    public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
        EssentialFilter[] result = new EssentialFilter[1];
        result[0] = this;    
        return result;
    }
}
```

In application.conf:

```
  #filters += Filters <- yes, it is commented since my Filters is in project's root
libraryDependencies += filters

play.filters {
 cors{
    # allow all paths
    pathPrefixes = ["/"]
    # allow all origins
    allowedOrigins = null
    allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
    # allow all headers
    allowedHttpHeaders = null
} ...
```

In build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ...,
  filters
)
```

Thank you all! :)

Comment: That needs to be configured on the server and is not related to Angular. If you use `withCredentials` the exact origin must be provided instead of just `*`. CORS only applies if the HTTP request is made to a different URL then where `index.html` was originally loaded, this is why it works if you enter the URL in the browser directly.

Comment: I agree, this is server side. I'm not sure what to do or look for with your answer, sorry.

Comment: Are you using iFrames?

Comment: can you paste your `cors` config and the request headers/info from the browser? my guess would be that this is just an issue with configuration. for example, if you follow the the docs, you might set `allowedHttpHeaders = ["Accept"]`, but angular might be sending other headers. an easy way to check if it is misconfiguration is to change your `cors` config to just contain `anyOriginAllowed = true` and nothing else.

Comment: @handler, I've updated the post, ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember having the same import issue since I think there were some repackaging changes for Filters in Play somewhere around `2.5.0`. And `DefaultHttpFilters` was replaced by `HttpFilters` during that refactoring.

Check the source code for the correct path to `HttpFilters`. Choose the correct tag for the version of Play you are using and then search down the source tree until you find `HttpFilters` and check the package. [This is the path for the Java API for v 2.5.0](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/2.5.0/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/http).

**From your post it seems you are using the Java API but are using the import for the Scala version.**

The imports for Play `2.5.0` are:-

Scala - `import play.api.http.HttpFilters`
Java - `import play.http.HttpFilters`

I'm using Play `2.5.0` (Scala though - not Java) and this import is working fine for me:-

```
import play.api.http.HttpFilters
```

From what you have posted I think you should try changing your problematic import to:-

```
import play.http.HttpFilters
```

---

Also, (as others have stated) I assume you have configured the package for your `Filters.java` file if you have not placed it in the root package.

This is the entry in my `application.conf` since I am using `package filters` rather than the default package.:-

```
play.http.filters = "filters.Filters"
```

Comment: This got me really close to the solution, please check the working code.

Comment: for 2.6 just add `play.filters.hosts {
  allowed = [ "localhost:9000", "localhost:4200"]
}` in configuration

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is to serve both static context and webservice from single origin. For example, for single domain, every URI except /api/* is meant to serve static content and /api/* is a reverse proxy to Java app. You may be specifically interested in [Grunt](https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy). nginx and Apache could also work.

For example in nginx you specify following configuration:

```
location /api {
    rewrite /api/(.*) /$1  break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}

location / {
    root   /var/www/location;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

And then you run your Java app listening on localhost, on port 9000. You are able to copy all your static content to location specified after "root" and get it served by nginx. You send all REST request to /api/method/name

Advantage of this solution is solid security and ability to configure SSL easily.

Comment: Can you please explain more about it or give me some references? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If it is **only** for **development purposes** you might try with a browser plugin to prevent CORS checks:

For instance, [cors everywhere](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/)  on Firefox or [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) in Chrome.

Anyway, in production environment you will have to serve JS assets and services from the same host or set Acces-Control-Allow-Origin header with the specific value for your services.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is for a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think that custom filter solves your problem:

```
import javax.inject.Inject

import play.api.http.DefaultHttpFilters
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter

class Filters @Inject() (corsFilter: CORSFilter)
  extends DefaultHttpFilters(corsFilter)
```

and in `application.conf`

```
play.http.filters = "filters.MyFilters"
```

configuration like this:

```
play.filters.cors {
  pathPrefixes = ["/some/path", ...]
  allowedOrigins = ["http://www.example.com", ...]
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST"]
  allowedHttpHeaders = ["Accept"]
  preflightMaxAge = 3 days
}
```

Comment: I can't import `play.api.http.DefaultHttpFilters` (cannot find symbol)

Comment: according to spec, you must append `libraryDependencies += filters` to sbt see this: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaCsrf#applying-a-global-csrf-filter

Comment: Did you try firstly, this example: https://github.com/dwhjames/play-cors/blob/master/src/main/scala/play/filters/cors/CORSFilter.scala  or, secondly, use `AbstractCORSPolicy` like alternative https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-filters-helpers/src/main/scala/play/filters/cors/AbstractCORSPolicy.scala#L322

Answer (score 0):

You do not show much from your project, so it is hard to understand, what a problem it may be. I do not think that there is any CORS issue here, because by default no any security filters are active. You can find [here](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/05/integration-play-angularjs-detached-projects.html), how you can integrate angular and Play.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of others working with Angular 4 front-end and lagom backend project. I have managed to solve this way.

*I added this line below in my build.sbt in both api and impl *

libraryDependencies += filters

*In my impl directory, i created folder filters and added the code below*

```
import play.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter;
import play.http.HttpFilters;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Filters implements HttpFilters {

    @Inject
    CORSFilter corsFilter;

    public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
        return new EssentialFilter[]{corsFilter.asJava()};
    }
}
```

*In my application.conf i added the code that follows*

```
play.filters.hosts {
  # Allow requests to example.com, its subdomains, and localhost:9000.
  allowed = ["localhost:5000", "localhost:9000"]
}

play.http.filters = "....filters.Filters"

play.filters.cors {
  # Filter paths by a whitelist of path prefixes
  pathPrefixes = ["/"]

  # The allowed origins. If null, all origins are allowed.
  allowedOrigins = null
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST"]
  allowedHttpHeaders = ["Accept"]
  preflightMaxAge = 3 days
}
```

After this, i restarted my lagom microservices and it worked like a charm.